# SSMS - Is it possible to pass additional connection parameters via Command Line?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms

I'm able to launch SQL Server Management Studio (2014) from command line using something like below.

```
ssms.exe -E -S myservername -D -mydatabasename
```

However, I'm not sure how to pass `additional connection parameters` such as `multisubnetfailover=true`

Is it possible to do this via commandline or through 'Target' on SSMS windows desktop properties?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. If you type `ssms.exe -?` or look [at the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162825.aspx) you'll see the list of possible options:

> Ssms
>       [scriptfile] [projectfile] [solutionfile]
>       [-S servername] [-d databasename] [-U username] [-P password]
>       [-E] [-nosplash] [-log [filename]?] [-?]

So there is no option to specify a connection string or additional connection properties.